Distribution of sample variance of the Student distribution $t(\nu)$
It's well known that the distribution of the sample variance $s_n^2$ of the normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ is $s_n^2 \sim  \frac{\chi_{n-1}^2}{n-1}$. 
Suppose I have a Student distribution $t(\nu)$ with $\nu > 2$ degrees of freedom and variance 1 (i.e. scale$=\sqrt{\frac{\nu - 2}{\nu}}$). What is the distribution of the sample variance of $t(\nu)$? Does it have variance in case when $\nu \leq 4$?

Maybe you could adapt a method like this to the t distribution instead of the normal distribution?

Unfortunately, it doesn't work, because Student distribution doesn't have a moment-generating function.

But I realized, that there is a simple formula for variance of sample variance, and, yeah, it doesn't have a variance in case when $\nu \leq 4$.

Would you mind posting it? I have never seen such a formula before

variance of sample variance in general case
